# Extracting text from a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting to write a function which will scan a range of elements which contains "*-chars" as a class. Once I've found the elements I want to take that particular class (eg max-chars) and extract the part of the class before the -. I can't use a simple split as elements could contain other classes which contain a - or even -chars.

So far I've managed the following:

```
var getLimitType = function (el) {
    var output = el.find('*[class*="-chars"]').filter(function () {
         return this.className.match(/(?:^|\s)-chars/);
    });

    var limitType = output.val().split("-").shift();
    var getVal = el.find('input').attr('maxlength');
    return limitType+'_'+getVal;
};
```

Obviously this doesn't work as limitType is trying to perform a split on a jQuery object instead of a string, however I can't figure out what to put in the blank line, I need something which will take all the classes from that object, work out which one I am looking for and returning only that one as a text string.

Comment: .find('*[class*="-chars"]') should be .find('[class*="-chars"]')

Comment: get all classess and split it by space like split(" ") and iterate it to find your *-chars class

Comment: @C-link both are same functional-wise, but they are different while seeing in the perspective of performance...!

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar that was my initial thought too, however for some reason "output.attr('class').split(" ");" returns an error "Uncaugh TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Comment: Are you trying something like this? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/t2hL9/1/). (_Check the result in console_)

Comment: Yeah I've tried that before but the array just ends up empty.

Answer (score 0):

Never quite found a desirable answer, however I managed to solve my issue with this work-around:

```
var getLimitType = function (element) {
    var ml = element.find('input').attr('maxlength');
    if (element.hasClass('exact-chars')) {
        return 'exact_'+ml;
    } else if (element.hasClass('min-chars')) {
        return 'min_'+ml;
    } else if (element.hasClass('max-chars')) {
        return 'max_'+ml;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};
```